# xpath correct using scrapy

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.http import Request

class PushpaSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'test'
    start_urls = ['https://ap-rk.com/advokat-panfilov-vladimir-vladimirovich-moskva-otzyvy-telefon-adres-chasy-raboty-foto/']

    def parse(self, response):
        website=response.xpath("//td//strong[contains(.,'Официальный сайт:')]/following-sibling::td/text()").get()
        yield{
            'website':website
        }
```

I want to try to extract `link` but they will give me nothing these is the page link https://ap-rk.com/advokat-panfilov-vladimir-vladimirovich-moskva-otzyvy-telefon-adres-chasy-raboty-foto/

Comment: what version of selenium are you using? (or is scrapy using)?

Comment: scrapy 2.5.0 version

Comment: @AmenAziz what exactly do you need from this page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nobody can stop you using a complex solution like scrapy, when the same result can be achieved in 2 lines of code (well, 3):

```
import pandas as pd

dfs = pd.read_html('https://ap-rk.com/advokat-panfilov-vladimir-vladimirovich-moskva-otzyvy-telefon-adres-chasy-raboty-foto/')
dfs[0]
```

This returns:

```
0   1
0   NaN Телефон: +7 (495) 646-0697
1   Рабочий адрес:  Москва
2   NaN г. Москва, ул. Бутырский вал, дом № 68, офис №403
3   Специализация:  корпоративное право предпринимательское право
4   Об адвокате:    NaN
5   Информация: Адвокатская палата: Республики Башкортостан Но...
6   Электронная почта:  order@chelovekizakon.ru
7   Официальный сайт:   https://chelovekizakon.ru
```

EDIT: as my attempt to suggesting a lesser complexity solution made the OP angry, here is the correct XPATH to locate the url in question:

```
"//td/strong[text()='Официальный сайт:']/parent::td//following-sibling::td"
```

Comment: Updated my answer (and tested it), let me know if it works for you.